# Neo4j - return node on max value

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am loading the data to neo4j via csv with below command

```
load csv with headers from "file:///path_to.csv" as file
merge (d:DIAGNOSIS {name:file.DIAGNOSIS_SYNONYM})
merge (dn:DRUG_NAME {name:file.DRUG_NAME})
merge (tc:TOTAL_COST {name:toFloat(file.TOTAL_COST)})
merge (cnt:COUNT {name:toInt(file.COUNT)})
merge (ac:AVERAGE_COST {name:toFloat(file.AVERAGE_COST)})
create (dn)-[:for]->(d)
create (d)-[:costs]->(tc)
create (tc)-[:count]->(cnt)
create (cnt)-[:avg_costs]->(ac)
```

Now i want to find the diagnosis with highest/lowest total_cost.

I have tried

```
MATCH ((dn)-[:for]-(d)-[:costs]-(tc)-[:count]-(cnt)-[:avg_costs]->(ac))
WITH d,tc, max(tc.name) as maximum
where tc.name= maximum
return d
```

However this returns all the diagnosis node. Can someone suggest me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use max() on a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36090701/how-to-use-max-on-a-collection)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are using only `d::DIAGNOSIS` and `tc:TOTAL_COST` why are you `MATCH`ing the whole path? I believe you can `MATCH` only `(d:DIAGNOSIS)-[:costs]-(tc:TOTAL_COST)` and ignore the rest.

Also remember to use labels whenever possible. Labels will improve the performance of your query.

I believe that using an `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` should work. Try:

```
MATCH ((d:DIAGNOSIS)-[:costs]-(tc:TOTAL_COST))
RETURN d
ORDER BY tc.name DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Alternatively you can first MATCH the maximum `tc.name` and use it in the `WHERE` of a second MATCH.

```
MATCH (tc:TOTAL_COST)
WITH  max(tc.name) AS maximum
MATCH ((d:DIAGNOSIS)-[:costs]-(tc:TOTAL_COST))
WHERE tc.name = maximum
RETURN d
```